# Is I am living used to mean I live?

Tags: present-simple

"I live" instead of "I am living" is not impossible when talking about temporary situations. However most books say the progressive not the simple present is used to talk about temporary situations.

If I am talking about my home. Can I say "I am living"? Grammar books have taught me to use the simple present for facts and the progressive for temporary actions but in movies and literature I often see these tenses are used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

“I live” refers to the present but implies the past and future as well.

“I am [currently] living” implies the present only.

However, since this is only implied, either can be clarified by context to mean the other.

Comment: Do you mean it's not impossible for a native speaker to say  "I am living" when talking about their hometown? The place where they were born and which they are not planning on leaving.

Comment: @AntoniaA It depends on the context. For instance, “I am still living in X” makes sense if they’ve never left, as does “I am living in X again” if they left and returned. But the emphasis there is on the (lack of) change, whereas “I live in X” puts emphasis on the place.